# Some menu items wont budge

Tags: php, admin-menu

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links');
        function remove_admin_menu_links(){
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'email@address.com' == $user->user_email ) {

                remove_menu_page('upload.php'); // Media - works(remove)

                remove_menu_page( 'gf_edit_forms' ); //Forms - doesn't work(visibile)

                remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page'); // Pages - works(removed)

                remove_menu_page('wpseo_dashboard'); // SEO  - works(remove)
                remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard'); // SEO  - works(remove)

                remove_menu_page('envanto-market'); // Envanto Market  - doesn't work(visibile)
                remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=envanto-market'); // Envanto Market - doesn't work(visibile)

                remove_menu_page('gadwp_settings'); // Google Analytics - doesn't work(visibile)
                remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=gadwp_settings'); // Google Analytics - doesn't work(visibile)
        }
    }

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menus_links' , 9999 );
```

Outlined above shows the action added to remove menu items from a specific admin users menu items.

I cant seem to be able to remove Forms, Envanto Market or Google Analytics. The rest of the menu items have been removed, bit I cant figure out why these few don't appear to moving.

If anyone can see why these menu items are still available?

Also, there is a full list of these menu items still available in the admin_bar_menu, new_Post option at the top of the page. If Anyone can point me in the right direction to remove these too?

I've tried adding to `functions.php:`

```
// admin_bar_menu hook
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'update_adminbar', 999);
```

and in the `/plugins/admin_bar.php :`

```
<?php
// update toolbar
function update_adminbar($wp_adminbar) {

  // remove unnecessary items
  $wp_adminbar->remove_node('wp-logo');
  $wp_adminbar->remove_node('customize');
  $wp_adminbar->remove_node('comments');
  $wp_adminbar->remove_node('post-new');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin bar is hooked incorrectly.It should be hooked to `wp_before_admin_bar_render`.

This is what I use (and works):

```
function alter_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'customize' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'ddw-gravityforms-toolbar' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'members-new-role' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-media' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-post' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-user' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'wp-logo' );
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'alter_admin_bar' );
```

Regarding the side menu I don't know. My first guess would be that you're using incorrect identifiers.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but now I need to change the access to specific users. I've replaced the global rule with the specific user as outlined in the remove_admin_menu_links as per email address, but it looses the top menu bar all together and doesn't give the user access to anything at all, just showing a blank window in the main section, no matter which menu item I choose.

Comment: Just to make clear, using the per users email option to does only remove access for that specific user. I still have access to everything with my login details including the main window to edit and add

Comment: in addition to the inability to remove certain menu items such as Forms, etc. It appears that Gravity have there own specific method to remove menu items

Comment: Can't you filter it with current_user_can ? Instead of by email ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo on your callback function name.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menus_links' , 9999 );
```

should be:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links' , 9999 );
```

If you correct that, the action will get fired later and the GADWP menu link will get removed.

Comment: brilliant! Needed new glasses!